# How does Tensorflow determine "operations necessary to produce the observable effects" for non-strict execution

Tags: tensorflow, denotational-semantics

I've been reading through the Ternsorflow documentation and have come to a section describing some of the differences between eager and graph execution. Graph execution is defined (described?) as being non-strict, in that

> "Graph execution only executes the operations necessary to produce the
> observable effects, which include:
>
> The return value of the function
> Documented well-known side-effects such as:
> Input/output operations, like tf.print
> Debugging operations, such as the assert functions in tf.debugging
> Mutations of tf.Variable
>
> This behavior is usually known as "Non-strict execution", and differs
> from eager execution, which steps through all of the program
> operations, needed or not."

An example given is how an "unneeded" operation will not throw an error:

```
@tf.function
def unused_return_graph(x):
  tf.gather(x, [20]) # unused
  return x

# Only needed operations are run during graph execution. The error is not raised.
print(unused_return_graph(tf.constant([5.0])))

Returns:

tf.Tensor([5.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

But,

```
#@tf.function
def unused_return_graph(x):
  tf.gather(x, [20]) # unused
  return x

# Only needed operations are run during graph execution. The error is not raised.
print(unused_return_graph(tf.constant([5.0])))
```

Returns:

```
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__GatherV2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} indices[0] = 20 is not in [0, 1) [Op:GatherV2]
```

`tf.gather(x, [20])` looks to me like it is needed to produce "the return value of a function", which in this case would be undefined. Why is this not so? What would be a case where tf.gather was deemed necessary? I suspect if I understood [Denotational Semantics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics#Bottom_and_Partial_Functions), I wouldn't have this question, but I'm having trouble slogging through it all and am hoping a succinct example might make things more clear.

---

Later thought: Could "unused" mean no variable values were changed or created?

Comment: The value returned by `gather` isn't used anywhere in the function.

Comment: @xdurch0 If returning it doesn't count as use, what does?

Comment: It's not being used though. The function just returns `x`, which is just the input. the `gather` operation is not needed to return `x`.

Comment: @xdurch0 - It returns a part of `x`, not all of `x`. However no values of `x` are changed, is this the sense in which it is unused? (PS - Sorry about an edit I made. Last night, I had meant to just put a line between my original post and my later thought. I used '=' instead of '-', which gave my last paragraph a big, bold font as if I were shouting it. That was not my intent. Hope it didn't seem obnoxious. Thx for taking the time to respond.

Comment: No. the point is that the function `unused_return_graph` simply returns `x`, and the `gather` operation is not at all needed to do that, so it is ignored. It also has no side effects such as changing `x` in some way, so `unused_return_graph` works the same way whether the `gather` op is called or not, so it can be ignored and isn't run when in graph mode. I also did not take any offense, don't worry. I just feel like we're talking about different things here.

Comment: Let me know if this is still not clear, then I will write an actual longer answer.

Comment: @xdurch0 - I think things are clear now. `tf.gather` returns a slice of x, however, it does not effect the output of the `unused_return_graph_function`. I could comment out the `tf.gather` line  and the function would still have the same output. But, if I replace `tf.gather(x, [20])` with `y=tf.gather(x, [20])` and also replace `return x` with `return y`, then `gather` function is being used and it will raise an error.